# How easy is it to game the altmetric score?

Tags: bibliometrics, research-dissemination, social-media

The altmetric score is a summary of the online attention a publication has received. More tweets, hits and chatter makes a bigger score. But what does the popularity contest mean?

I've heard of researchers being officially judged by their Research Gate scores, but this one is new to me.

Have you ever tried to boost your altmetric score? Is it as easy as just posting a [link](https://www.liberquarterly.eu/article/10.18352/lq.10289/)? http://dx.doi.org/10.18352/lq.10289 Here's my two cents to help with the experiment.

Comment: Someone please, please tell me no one uses a metric based on mentions in tweets for anything of importance in academia - hiring, promotion, grants, or otherwise. Academics needing social media managers and influencer-based campaigns for career development is just too dystopic to bear.

Comment: @BrianH to think about it, news press impact isn't that different, and citation scores are merely an extra brush away of common sense off. Measuring research by popularity has been a reality for too long, and the majority doesn't want to change that. It can only grow worse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do things like tweet about your paper, and you should. It will increase your altmetrics score, but not as much as dozens of people RTing your tweet because they thought your paper rocked.

I suggested initially that you might be able to make a bot that tweets about your paper 5 times a minute, but people would likely pick up on that and it could be bad for your reputation in your field. @Scientist says in a comment that won't work, but seeing how Altmetrics is impacted by my twitter discussions of my papers I think it isn't just once per account if it's different days and different text, so I still suspect you could hack something up, but I still wouldn't advise it.

The bottom line is that many of the things you could do to "hack" Altmetrics would actually be promoting your research which is what people want you to do in the first place. There's no point to doing work no one reads.

Comment: One RT bot wouldn’t give more than one altmetric point per paper because it counts tweets *per account*. One would need several bots to get a good boost, and I think creating these numerous bots would infringe Twitter rules.

Comment: @Scientist Thanks for that, though I'm not sure you're right if the tweets are permuted. Also, I'm afraid you might be overestimating the altmetrics scores of the average academic paper, even doing this a few times might have a big impact, and could be done by hand if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Like any metric, there’s a potential for gaming of altmetrics: 
>   Anyone with enough time on their hands can artificially inflate the 
>   altmetrics for their research. That’s why altmetrics providers like 
>   Altmetric, PLOS and SSRN have measures in place to identify and correct for 
>   gaming. Don’t forget to look at the underlying qualitative data to see who 
>   has been talking about the research, and what they’ve been saying.

I conclude it is very easy to game the score.  Gaming is also easy to detect.  Gaming altmetrics is neither ethical nor useful.

https://www.altmetric.com/about-altmetrics/what-are-altmetrics/

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the point of *gaming* one's paper Altmetric score, although I certainly see the point of **boosting** a paper Altmetric score. Sure: both mean increasing this number on purpose, but it is the purpose which is ultimately different.

To the best of knowledge the Altmetric score in itself has no official nor institutional value. My colleagues are next to ignorant about the altmetric counts of papers they published, what to say that they read. What's more, when you understand the details behind altmetric scoring, you'll be logically unable to take it as a measure for paper quality.

Altmetric scores measure the online visibility of a given paper. It works as a thermometer for the chance that anyone at random will get exposed to a given paper. More remotely, that paper's potential of being cited in the short- medium-term. Therefore, I do see some value in boosting a paper's altmetric score, and I am pretty sure that are a lot of researchers actively doing it.

Your altmetric score goes up immediately as you successfully promote and divulge your papers online. This is something that many researchers have been doing naturally, for different reasons, and surely even more nowadays, encouraged by seeing their scores going up dressed in fancy colours.

I would call it gaming altmetric score. I'd say that altmetric has benefitted science communicators via **gamification**.